# How to get each value in combobox dropdown list?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, combobox

How to get each value in combobox dropdown list?

here is what i try

```
        For Each obj In cbComboBox.Items
        MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString)
    Next
```

it just showing up the combobox datasource object, it not showing, what is in the items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a class type to extract? This is an `objectCollection`. When you add things to them there are stored as objects. So cast the obj back to it's type and then proceed.

```
For Each obj In cbComboBox.Items
    Dim item = TryCast(obj, {the object type or class})
    If Not item Is Nothing Then
      'use the item as it is converted correctly
    End If
Next
```

Comment: TryCast(obj, {the object type or class}) <-- what object type i should choose?

Answer (score 1):

```
For each item As DataRowView In cbComboBox.Items
        msgbox(item.Row("valuecolumnname"))
    next
```

Just thought i would add this also as another option.